# 'TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined' after running npm run start.android in an angular environment

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

So using `npm run start.android` while using https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced runs the project in android. I installed all the dependencies with `npm install` and prepared the project correctly.

Unfortunately after using the command I get an error `TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined`.

**I tried searching for solutions online** but I was not able to do any of them because I'm not really understanding why this is happening.

Running `tns doctor --log tail` showed there was problem with the installation of mobile environments (android and ios) so it automatically prompted me to try and fix it by installing several dependencies and packages.

Amongst these changes `$ANDROID_HOME` was also added to the bash profile but strangely although I have android sdk installed from sdk 18 to 25 it seems running `tns doctor --log tail` gives me a message about "you need to have at least android SDK 22 installed".

What should I do to fix this? Do you need more information?

I've been losing my time too much over it by now and I really have no idea on what to do.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: which version of node are you running (node 6.11 latest ?)                    npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install

Comment: Could you provide more info on your environment? system? java version?  do you have JAVA_HOME path?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
npm install -g nativescript
tns doctor
Follow the steps and say yes to every question.

If you're on windows then iOS will not work.
Alternatively if tns doctor doesn't work you can install the emulator for android by setting up android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html